# Diferencias entre limpiar el búfer en C

Tags: c

Usualmente limpio el búfer de stdin con este código:

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Pero la mayoría me dicen que es más recomendable hacerlo así:

```
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

¿Por qué agregan el ch != EOF? Eso es lo que no logro entender.
¿Qué consecuencias traería la forma como la hago yo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilizar el segundo, hace mas practica la validación ya que a parte de verificar si es un salto de linea, también verifica que sea un End Of File ([EOF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF)) para salir del ciclo.

En pocas palabras el código básicamente omite todos los caracteres hasta la próxima nueva línea.

Por lo tanto es recomendable usar la segunda

```
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Y si solo quiero que el programa siga hasta el final de la linea?. ¿Por que usar EOF?. @TheVicShow

Comment: @DanielBriceño Lo puedes hacer y funcionará. El problema es que si en el búfer del teclado hay un `EOF`, esto generaría un bucle infinito. Por ejemplo, intenta ingresar el caracter `EOF` desde la consola con `CTRL + Z` (para windows) y te darás cuenta del bucle infinito.

Comment: Buena respuesta.