# Error al leer un caracter en c

Tags: c, caracteres, scanf

Tengo un pequeño problema con los caracteres en c. En una de las prácticas me piden repetir el programa mientras el usuario decida seguir introduciendo datos.

Este es el programa:

```
void introducirPosiciónB(float *Xb,float *Yb) {
     printf("Posición (x) de la persona? ");
     scanf("%f",Xb);
     printf("Posición (y) de la persona ");
     scanf("%f",Yb);
}

int main(){
     float Xa, Ya, Xb, Yb;
     char eleccion;
     introducirPosiciónA(&Xa,&Ya,);
     do{
     introducirPosiciónB(&Xb,&Yb);
     printf("\n\nOtro? (y or n)"); //Aquí esta el problema
     scanf("%c",&eleccion);
     }
     while(eleccion!='n');
     return 0;
 }
```

Las funciones de dentro del main me vienen ya dadas por lo que eso está bien.

**El problema surge cuando al llegar al scanf del carácter avanza sin pararse a leerlo, lo ignora y repite el programa sin dejarte opción a introducir n**

He probado también por cambiar el scanf por getch(eleccion) pero tampoco funciona.

Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradecería mucho.

Gracias por leerlo al menos.

**SOLUCIÓN:**

scanf(" %c", &eleccion);

Repito muchísimas gracias a todos!!!

Comment: cual es el código de `introducirPosicionB` e `introducirPosicionA`??

Comment: ```void introducirPosiciónB(float *Xb,float *Yb){
    printf("Posición (x) de la persona? ");
    scanf("%f",Xb);
    printf("Posición (y) de la persona ");
    scanf("%f",Yb);
}```  ambos son iguales

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y pon el código ahí

Comment: Se necesitan dos porque A es fijo pero B va cambiando cada vez que se repita, entre leer a B y repetir el programa me falta introducir una función para calcular a que distancia están pero todavía no la tengo terminada y la quite por si era el problema.

Comment: Cuando se ejecuta la funcion `introducirPosiciónA` el buffer del teclado queda sucio.. Asi que cuando intentes pedir el caracter, no pausara el programa. Tienes varias soluciones, la primera es [limpiar el buffer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233445/diferencias-entre-limpiar-el-b%c3%bafer-en-c) antes del `scanf("%c", ..)` o lo que puedes hacer, es descartar el salto de linea de esta forma: `scanf(" %c", &eleccion)` (dejando un espacio antes del especificador).

Comment: Muchas gracias, ```scanf(" %c", &eleccion)``` funciona!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cuando tecleas "n" (cualquier caracter), estás ingresando dos caracteres: "n" y un "\n".

Con

```
scanf("%c",&eleccion);
```

lees el primer caracter y dejas el "\n" en el buffer de entrada. Cuando vas a ejecutar el siguiente `scanf`, éste encuentra el "\n" y te lo devuelve.

Usa esto:

```
scanf("%c%*c",&eleccion);
```

El formato `%*c`, con un asterico entremedio, significa que hay que leer un caracter y descartarlo.

Nota: No he probado esto en Windows; puede que el buffer contenga '\r\n', dos caracteres en lugar de uno. Alguien aportara un comentario clarificador.

**Demo**

Elimine la función `introducirPosicion` y otras declaraciones irrelevantes. La versión mínima, completa que aborda el problema es:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char eleccion;
    
    do {
        printf("\n\nOtro? (y or n)"); //Aquí esta el problema
        scanf("%c%*c", &eleccion);
    } while (eleccion != 'n');
    return 0;
}
```

produce:

```
Otro? (y or n)y


Otro? (y or n)n

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 2s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: Gracias, no sabia lo que significaba %*c pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @Paul. Agregue un ejemplo en mi respuesta para ilustrar mejor el punto.

Comment: Eliminado el código anterior y escribiendo el tuyo de la demo si espera a la respuesta y para al introducir n. Si vuelvo a meter la función externa (introducirPosicion) no para nunca

Comment: @Paul. En `introducirPosicion` tienes el mismo problema de no leer el '\n' con que termina el valor en punto flotante.