# El programa debe preguntar si desea finalizar o no

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

El programa preguntará al usuario si desea finalizar o no, en caso que diga que si deberá terminar la ejecución no se como hacer para que funcione bien, básicamente lo probé de mil formas pero cuando lo ejecuto me dice si deseo continuar pero no hace nada, solo empieza a preguntar lo mismo una y otra vez y no puede parar hasta que cierro la ventana, éste es el código que debo implementar.

Este es el código que uso para tratar de salir de la ejecución del programa, pero no me funciona. En el código completo se muestra bien donde está ubicada esta sección de código.

```
do
  {      printf("Desea salir del programa (s/n)?:");
         scanf("%c", &salir);
  }       while((salir != 's') || (salir != 'S'));
```

Este es el código completo:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    void Imprimir(int azt1, int espacio, int azt2)
    {
       for(int i = 1; i<= azt1; i++)
       {
          printf("*");
       }

       for(int i = 1; i<=espacio;i++)
       {
          printf(" ");
       }

       for(int i = 1; i<=azt2; i++)
       {
          printf("*");
       }

       printf("\n");
    }
    int main()
    {
    char salir;
        int n, opcion = 0, N1, N2, N3, num, i;
        do
    {

    system("cls");
        printf("1. Mayor de 3 numeros ");
        
        printf("\n2. Multiplos");
        
        printf("\n3. Mostrar el mensaje seguir ");
        
        printf("\n4. impresion del numero 8 ");
        
        printf("\n5. Salir ");
        
        printf("\n -Para volver al menu pulse Enter-");
        
        printf("\n\n introduzca un numero de 1 - 5: ");
        
        scanf("%d", & opcion);
     
        switch (opcion)
        
        
        case 1:
            
            {
            
        printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &N1 );
        printf("ingrese el segundo numero: ");
        scanf("%d", & N2);
        printf ("Ingrese el tercer numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &N3);
        
        if (N1 > N2 && N1 > N3){
            printf ("el numero mayor es: %d ");
        }
        else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 >N3){
            printf ("el numero mayor es: %d");
            
        }
        else if ( N3 > N1 && N3 > N2){
            printf( "el mayor numero es: %d");
        }
        else if ( N1 > N3 && N1 == N2){
            printf("El numero mayor es: %d" );
        }
        else if ( N1 > N2 && N2 == N3){
            printf (" el numero mayor es: %d" );
        }
        else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 ==N3){
            printf("el mayor numero es: %d");
        }
        else{
            printf (" Los tres numeros son iguales ");
            
            
     }
     
    getch ();


    break;

        

                
            
                
        case 2:
                
        printf("Este programa te permite calcular los multiplos de un numero");
        printf("\n ingrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("su multiplo es: \n");
        
        for (i=0; i<=1000; i=num+i)
        {
            printf("%d \n",i);
    }

    break;

    case 3:
        char seguir;
        int contador, acumulador;
        acumulador =0;
        contador =-1;
        
        {
            printf("este es un programa que cuenta cuantas veces se imprime una palabra, si pregunta seguir? usted pone un Si, de lo contrario introduzca un -1 \n");
            
    }


    char salir;
    do
    {

            printf(" seguir?");
            
            scanf("%d", & seguir);
            acumulador +=seguir;
            acumulador += seguir;
            contador++;
            fflush(stdin);
        }while ( seguir!=-1);
        printf("\n ha introducido %d impresiones", contador);
        
        
         {      printf("Desea salir del programa (s/n)?:");
                fflush(stdin);
               scanf("%c", &salir);
       }       while((salir < 's') || (salir > 'S'));
     

        getch ();
        return 0;


    break;
          case 4:
    {
            
        

    for(int i = 1; i<=2;i++)
    {
       Imprimir(12,0,0);
       Imprimir(12,0,0);
       Imprimir(3,6,3);
       Imprimir(3,6,3);
    }

    Imprimir(12,0,0);
    Imprimir(12,0,0);
    }
    do
     {      printf("Desea salir del programa (s/n)?:");
                fflush(stdin);
               scanf("%c", &salir);
       }       while((salir < 's') || (salir > 'S'));
       

    getch();

    }

      } while (opcion !=5);
        system ("pause");
        return 0;

    }
Éste es el código que cree el cual debo introducir esa condición.
```

Comment: les pasaré el código que cree, el cual debe tener esa funcion, es un menú de opciones, y en cada opción debe preguntar si desea terminar o no la ejecución

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al leer un caracter en c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394892/error-al-leer-un-caracter-en-c)

Comment: si amigo gracias, esta vez si lo termina, pero como hago para que vuelva al menú si selecciono que No quiero terminar el programa?

Comment: Tienes mal la condición del while `(salir != 's') || (salir != 'S')`, se cumple siempre (cualquier letra es distinta de s **ó** de S). Tal vez, querías `(salir != 's') && (salir != 'S')` (la letra debe ser distinta de s **y** de S)

Comment: ahhh si eso me habian explicado, pero cuando selecciono que no quiero salir me repite lo mismo, que debo introducir para que me envíe de vuelta al menú?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está muy desordenado, pudiste haber incluido cada código de las opciones que das en una función diferente, para que en el `int main()` no te quedara un código demasiado largo y desordenado, además hacen falta saltos de línea, reparar la opción 1 que realmente No encuentra el número mayor y solo te devuelve una dirección en memoria.

```
 {      printf("Desea salir del programa (s/n)?:");
            fflush(stdin);
           scanf("%c", &salir);
   }       while((salir < 's') || (salir > 'S'));
```

Esto era completamente innecesario para hacer la pregunta, además que tienes errores de sintaxis ¿Dónde esté el `do`  del `do while` ?, Estás dentro de un `do while`, y escribes otro sólo para hacer la pregunta, de estar bien la sintaxis te generaría un bucle dentro de otro bucle, lo cual no es nada eficiete.

En el `switch(opcion)` , no añadistes el `default`, lo cual te hubiera resultado muy útil a la hora de que el usuario halla elegido la opción incorrecta, en vez de validar eso en el primer `do while`.

```
switch (opcion)
    
    
    case 1:
        
        {
        
    printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &N1 );
    printf("ingrese el segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", & N2);
    printf ("Ingrese el tercer numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &N3);
    
    if (N1 > N2 && N1 > N3){
        printf ("el numero mayor es: %d ");
    }
    else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 >N3){
        printf ("el numero mayor es: %d");
        
    }
    else if ( N3 > N1 && N3 > N2){
        printf( "el mayor numero es: %d");
    }
    else if ( N1 > N3 && N1 == N2){
        printf("El numero mayor es: %d" );
    }
    else if ( N1 > N2 && N2 == N3){
        printf (" el numero mayor es: %d" );
    }
    else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 ==N3){
        printf("el mayor numero es: %d");
    }
    else{
        printf (" Los tres numeros son iguales ");
        
        
 }
 
getch ();


break;

    

            
        
            
    case 2:
            
    printf("Este programa te permite calcular los multiplos de un numero");
    printf("\n ingrese un numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("su multiplo es: \n");
    
    for (i=0; i<=1000; i=num+i)
    {
        printf("%d \n",i);
}

break;

case 3:
    char seguir;
    int contador, acumulador;
    acumulador =0;
    contador =-1;
    
    {
        printf("este es un programa que cuenta cuantas veces se imprime una palabra, si pregunta seguir? usted pone un Si, de lo contrario introduzca un -1 \n");
        
}


char salir;
do
{

        printf(" seguir?");
        
        scanf("%d", & seguir);
        acumulador +=seguir;
        acumulador += seguir;
        contador++;
        fflush(stdin);
    }while ( seguir!=-1);
    printf("\n ha introducido %d impresiones", contador);
    
    
     {      printf("Desea salir del programa (s/n)?:");
            fflush(stdin);
           scanf("%c", &salir);
   }       while((salir < 's') || (salir > 'S'));
 

    getch ();
    return 0;


break;
      case 4:
{
        
    

for(int i = 1; i<=2;i++)
{
   Imprimir(12,0,0);
   Imprimir(12,0,0);
   Imprimir(3,6,3);
   Imprimir(3,6,3);
}

Imprimir(12,0,0);
Imprimir(12,0,0);
}
do
 {      printf("Desea salir del programa (s/n)?:");
            fflush(stdin);
           scanf("%c", &salir);
   }       while((salir < 's') || (salir > 'S'));
   

getch();

}
```

El `exit(-1)` lo que hace es sacarte del programa inmediatamente, lo que junto con el `if` crea  la condición de que si el usuario quiere salir o no del programa. Pienso que esa pregunta la deberías hacer cada vez que termina de ejecutarse una opción del `switch()`

```
int main() {
    char salir;
    int n, N1, N2, N3, num, i,opcion;
    for(;;) {

        system("cls");
        printf("1. Mayor de 3 numeros ");

        printf("\n2. Multiplos");

        printf("\n3. Mostrar el mensaje seguir ");

        printf("\n4. impresion del numero 8 ");

        printf("\n5. Salir ");

        printf("\n -Para volver al menu pulse Enter-");

        printf("\n\n introduzca un numero de 1 - 5: ");

        scanf("%d", & opcion);

        switch (opcion) {

        case 1:

            printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
            scanf("%d", &N1 );
            printf("ingrese el segundo numero: ");
            scanf("%d", & N2);
            printf ("Ingrese el tercer numero: ");
            scanf("%d", &N3);

            if (N1 > N2 && N1 > N3) {
                printf ("el numero mayor es: %d ");
            } else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 >N3) {
                printf ("el numero mayor es: %d");

            } else if ( N3 > N1 && N3 > N2) {
                printf( "el mayor numero es: %d");
            } else if ( N1 > N3 && N1 == N2) {
                printf("El numero mayor es: %d" );
            } else if ( N1 > N2 && N2 == N3) {
                printf (" el numero mayor es: %d" );
            } else if ( N2 > N1 && N2 ==N3) {
                printf("el mayor numero es: %d");
            } else {
                printf (" Los tres numeros son iguales ");
            }
            getch ();
        break;






        case 2:

            printf("Este programa te permite calcular los multiplos de un numero");
            printf("\n ingrese un numero: ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            printf("su multiplo es: \n");

            for (i=0; i<=1000; i=num+i) {
                printf("%d \n",i);
            }

        break;

        case 3:
            char seguir;
            int contador, acumulador;
            acumulador =0;
            contador =-1;

            {
                printf("este es un programa que cuenta cuantas veces se imprime una palabra, si pregunta seguir? usted pone un Si, de lo contrario introduzca un -1 \n");

            }


            char salir;
            do {

                printf(" seguir?");

                scanf("%d", & seguir);
                acumulador +=seguir;
                acumulador += seguir;
                contador++;
                fflush(stdin);
            } while ( seguir!=-1);
            printf("\n ha introducido %d impresiones", contador);
            getch ();
            return 0;


        break;

        case 4:

            for(int i = 1; i<=2; i++) {
                Imprimir(12,0,0);
                Imprimir(12,0,0);
                Imprimir(3,6,3);
                Imprimir(3,6,3);
            }

            Imprimir(12,0,0);
            Imprimir(12,0,0);

        break;

        default:
            printf("\nOpcion Incorrecta, Intentelo de nuevo!!!\n");
        break;

        }


    getch();

    printf("Desea salir del programa (s/n)?:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &salir);

    if (salir == 's' || salir == 'S'){
        exit(-1);
    }
    getch();

    }


}
```

Estás usando la sintaxis de C en C++, te recomiendo que busques información sobre otras librerías que puedes usar en C++.