# Bucle for salta los scanf que incluyen %[^\n]

Tags: c

Estaba trabajando con estructuras. Leí que se puede ingresar espacios en un string a través de poner `%[^\n]` en el `scanf`, pero en el `for` no parece funcionar: se salta esos `scanf`; fuera del `for` sí funcionan.
Quería saber qué solución le puedo dar a este problema.

```
int num;

struct persona registro [100];

printf ("Ingrese el numero de personas a registrar (minimo 3): ");
scanf ("%d", &num);

while (num<3){
    
    printf ("Debe ingresar al menos 3 personas: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num);
    
}

printf ("\n");

for (int i = 1 ; i<=num ; i++){
    
    printf ("Persona %d \n\n", i);
    
    printf ("Ingrese el apellido: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",registro[i].apellido);
    
    printf ("Ingrese el nombre: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", registro[i].nombre);
    
    printf ("Ingrese la edad: ");
    scanf ("%d", &registro[i].edad);
    
    printf ("Ingrese la altura: ");
    scanf ("%d", &registro[i].altura);
    
    printf ("Ingrese la profesion u oficio: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", registro[i].profesion);
    
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> > Bucle for salta los scanf que incluyen %[^\n]

El formato `%[^\n]` le indica a `scanf` que debe leer los caracteres hasta encontrar un salto de línea. También debemos tomar en cuenta que la función `scanf` dejará un salto de línea en el búfer del teclado cuando se pida un dato de tipo `int` o un `string`.

Analicemos este pedazo de código:

```c
printf ("Ingrese el apellido: ");
scanf("%[^\n]",registro[i].apellido);
    
printf ("Ingrese el nombre: ");
scanf ("%[^\n]", registro[i].nombre);
```

Al principio el búfer está limpio, entonces, `scanf` pausa el programa y pide un *apellido*, el usuario lo ingresa y luego `scanf` lee los caracteres hasta ver un *salto de línea* pero `scanf` no lee el salto de línea y lo deja en el búfer. **Así que el búfer quedó sucio.**

Luego, se pide al usuario que ingrese el nombre pero aquí hay un problema, `scanf` no pausará el programa y esto se debe porque hay un salto de línea en el búfer, entonces, `scanf` leería lo que haya en el búfer hasta encontrar el salto de línea y el búfer sigue quedando sucio.

Así que las demás llamadas fallarán, a excepción de esta:

```c
printf ("Ingrese la edad: ");
scanf ("%d", &registro[i].edad);
```

Aquí `scanf` sí pausará el programa, a pesar que el búfer quedó con un salto de línea, lo descarta pero mucho cuidado, sí el búfer quedó con más caracteres, la lectura falla.

La solución es [limpiar el búfer del teclado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233445/diferencias-entre-limpiar-el-b%C3%BAfer-en-c) con este código:

```c
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Lo podemos reutilizar usando funciones:

```c
void clearBuffer()
{
    char ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}
```

El código es simple, el bucle leerá los caracteres del búfer hasta encontrar un salto de línea o el caracter [EOF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF).

Esta función la puedes invocar en tu código:

```c
for (int i = 1 ; i<=num ; i++)
{
    printf ("Persona %d \n\n", i);
    
    printf ("Ingrese el apellido: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",registro[i].apellido);
    clearBuffer();
    printf ("Ingrese el nombre: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", registro[i].nombre);
    clearBuffer();
    printf ("Ingrese la edad: ");
    scanf ("%d", &registro[i].edad);
    clearBuffer();
    printf ("Ingrese la altura: ");
    scanf ("%d", &registro[i].altura);
    clearBuffer();
    printf ("Ingrese la profesion u oficio: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", registro[i].profesion);
    clearBuffer();
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Esto debería de funcionar pero es medio tedioso estar llamando esta función a cada rato, tal vez lo *ideal* sería delegar la responsibilidad de leer un dato a una función propia:

```c
int myscanf(const char* format, void* variable)
{
    int result = scanf(format, variable);
    clearBuffer();
    return result;
}
```

Luego puedes llamar la función así:

```c
for (int i = 1 ; i<=num ; i++)
{
    printf ("Persona %d \n\n", i);
    
    printf ("Ingrese el apellido: ");
    myscanf("%[^\n]",registro[i].apellido);
    printf ("Ingrese el nombre: ");
    myscanf("%[^\n]", registro[i].nombre);
    printf ("Ingrese la edad: ");
    myscanf("%d", &registro[i].edad);
    printf ("Ingrese la altura: ");
    myscanf("%d", &registro[i].altura);
    printf ("Ingrese la profesion u oficio: ");
    myscanf("%[^\n]", registro[i].profesion);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Con esto garantizas que el **búfer del teclado siempre esté limpio.**

**Observación:**

Mucho cuidado usar `scanf` para leer cadenas, esto podría provocar un desbordamiento de búfer. Te recomiendo leer este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383852/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-un-desbordamiento-de-b%C3%BAfer-cuando-se-pide-una-cadena-con-scanf).

También tienes otra opción para leer cadenas con espacios: [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).