# Porque si tengo los incrementos de un for de 1 en 1 al momento de imprimir hace saltos?

Tags: array, c

Estoy haciendo mis deberes, ya tengo un rato, sin embargo, no encuentro la razón por la cual funciona mal el codigo (es en c++) y no encuentro donde está el error, ayuda :( [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//Utilizar un array de tipo "Char" para solicitar los datos del usuario e imprimirlos al finalizar el programa//

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){    
int can, cont;
char nombre[can];
printf("Escriba la cantidad de caracteres que se van a ingresar: \n");
    scanf("%i", &can);
    for(cont = 1; cont <= can; cont++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca el caracter numero %i para registrarlo: ", cont);
        scanf("%c", &nombre[cont]);
    }
        printf("Los datos ingresados fueron: %c", nombre[can]);
return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Este código parece C. Si es así, ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/447566/bucle-for-salta-los-scanf-que-incluyen-n y es un problema [muy común](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%5D+salta+scanf) cuando se empieza con estos lenguajes.

Comment: En primer lugar, he tenido que añadir un define con el máximo tamaño de los datos a ingresar (inventado) y definir "nombre" como "char nombre[DEFINE_MAX]", luego he cambiado el %c del scanf con %s y funciona correctamente. Puedes ver el resultado en https://onlinegdb.com/4L0bFYx1k

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, no estás programando en C++, sino, en C. Son dos lenguajes diferentes, tienen sus similitudes, sí, pero esto no lo hace equivalentes.

Con respecto a lo otro, tu código tiene más de un error.

Esto es un [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length array) y lo estás usando mal:

```c
int can, cont;
char nombre[can];
```

La variable `can` no ha sido inicializado, por lo que tiene un valor basura y lo estás usando como longitud variable en `nombre`, esto está mal, esto conduce un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido), el programa puede funcionar o puede que no, el comportamiento es arbitrario.

La manera correcta es usar el VLA después de pedir el valor para la variable `can`:

```c
printf("Escriba la cantidad de caracteres que se van a ingresar: \n");
scanf("%i", &can);
char nombre[can];
```

Ahora la variable `can` si tiene un valor apropiado para usarlo como longitud en `nombre`.

Sin embargo, el código sigue teniendo un error lógico en esta parte:

```c
for(cont = 1; cont <= can; cont++)
```

La condición de salida no está bien: `cont <= can`, estás usando el operador incorrecto, al hacerlo de esta manera [desbordas el array](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) y conduces un comportamiento indefinido. No debes pasarte de los límites del array. Para recorrer un array se empieza desde el índice `0` y se termina hasta el índice `N - 1` (donde `N` es la cantidad máxima de elementos del array).

Así que el *for* debe ser cambiado a esto:

```c
for(cont = 0; cont < can; cont++)
```

Pero aun hay otro problema:

```c
printf("Los datos ingresados fueron: %c", nombre[can]);
```

La expresión `nombre[can]` devuelve un `char`, es decir, devuelve únicamente un dato y lo que se quiere es devolver más de un dato. Así que el especificador de formato `%c` no es el adecuado para este caso ni tampoco el operador de indexación `[]`. Debes usar el especificador `%s` para imprimir los datos completos:

```c
printf("Los datos ingresados fueron: %s", nombre);
```

Con todos los cambios mencionados, el código quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int can, cont;
    printf("Escriba la cantidad de caracteres que se van a ingresar: \n");
    scanf("%i", &can);
    char nombre[can];
    for(cont = 0; cont < can; cont++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca el caracter numero %i para registrarlo: ", cont + 1);
        scanf("%c", &nombre[cont]);
    }
    printf("Los datos ingresados fueron: %s", nombre);
    return 0;
}
```

Ahora sí vamos al problema principal:

> > Porque si tengo los incrementos de un for de 1 en 1 al momento de imprimir hace saltos?

Te explico lo que está pasando:

Cuando el usuario ingresa la cantidad de caracteres que se van a ingresar y presiona el `ENTER`, ese `ENTER` genera un salto de línea (`\n`) y se guarda en el búfer del teclado, luego en la primera iteración del bucle for, la función `scanf` no se detendrá para la espera de un nueva caracter, **porque leerá el caracter de salto de línea que quedó en el búfer del teclado**. Por esa razón hace ese "salto".

Luego en la segunda iteración, la función `scanf` si se detiene a la espera de un nuevo caracter **porque el búfer del teclado está vacío**.

Pienso que con esto puedes descifrar fácilmente porque en la tercera iteración la función `scanf` no se detiene, eso te lo dejo como tarea.

La solución más simple es decirle a la función `scanf` que ignore el salto de línea y que no lo lea:

```c
// Hay que dejar un espacio en blanco en el especificador %c
scanf(" %c", &nombre[cont]);
```

Pero esto código sigue teniendo problemas. Cualquier array de caracteres en C debe terminar con un caracter nulo (`\0`) y no lo veo por ninguna parte.

**¡Hay que dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo!** Si no lo haces, la función `printf` desbordará el array (esto es malo porque genera un comportamiento indefinido):

```c
printf("Los datos ingresados fueron: %s", nombre);
```

El código final quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int can, cont;
    printf("Escriba la cantidad de caracteres que se van a ingresar: \n");
    scanf("%i", &can);
    // Hay que dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo.
    can = can + 1;
    char nombre[can];
    // Después asignamos el caracter nulo.
    nombre[can - 1] = '\0';
    // La condición "cant - 1" es para no sobrescribir el caracter nulo.
    for(cont = 0; cont < can - 1; cont++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca el caracter numero %i para registrarlo: ", cont + 1);
        scanf(" %c", &nombre[cont]);
    }
    printf("Los datos ingresados fueron: %s", nombre);
    return 0;
}
```

### Observaciones

**1.** No uses los [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Los VLAs fueron eliminados a partir del estándar `C11`, por lo que tu código pierde portabilidad, puede funcionar en un compilador pero en otro tal vez no. En lugar de los VLAs, deberías de reservar memoria dinámica. Aquí hay un [tutorial](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Matrices_Dinamicas).

**2.** Trata de minimizar el ciclo de vida de las variables (creeme que ayuda mucho a la lectura del código y evita posibles errores), no lo agreges al inicio del programa. Por ejemplo, la variable `cont` se podía declarar directamente en el for.

**3.** Trata de darle nombres significativos a las variables. Por ejemplo, ¿qué significa `can`? Un buen nombre sería: `cantidad`. O ¿qué significa `cont`? No lo sé pero un buen nombre sería: `contador` o `i` (es un nombre que se usa solamente para iterar en los bucles).